# PG&E's Groundline distribution system

Tags: cables, distribution-network, outdoors

The other day I saw an article reporting how PG&E is planning to use "tech" to achieve its target to underground 10,000 miles.

They demo'ed something called a "Groundline distribution system".
I found a patent here titled  ["Ground level primary electric distribution system" (US11621549B2)](https://patents.google.com/patent/US11621549B2)

Is this actually a thing that will work at scale?

Won't they have to make changes to the National Electrical Code to make this compliant?

> The utility also unveiled its new groundline distribution system,
> which entails undergrounding 10,000 miles of lines in its 44,000-mile
> system using ground level conduits, instead of spending more to dig
> deeper and tear up rock and the concrete and asphalt of streets.
>
> The program started last year with 180 miles of cable brought down
> from above, where contact with trees and animals can start fires. It’s
> on pace for 350 miles this year. PG&E officials said the process
> typically costs about $3.5 million per mile of cable going
> underground.
>
> The new method — which inserts the cable into a
> hard surface that typically can’t be cut open with everyday tools (and
> withstands being run over by semi-trucks without damage) will cost
> about $1.5 million to $2 million per mile and be done 2-3 times
> faster. The boxes can be put a few inches into the ground, but without
> the typical fuss of digging trenches.

[image: A cutaway model of PG&E’s groundline distribution system.2]

Comment: Do you think it's been made up?

Comment: I wonder what voltage range is intended for this. Up to 12kV seems feasible; 120kV? Probably suffers too much armor-cable loss. If used with HVDC this wouldn't be as much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't they have to change the NEC to make this code compliant?

No, they would have to change [NESC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Electrical_Safety_Code).

Utilities running wires on their side of the customer electric meter are governed by [the NESC codebook](https://standards.ieee.org/products-programs/nesc/), not NEC.

Or in California, [GO95](https://ia.cpuc.ca.gov/gos/GO95/go_95_startup_page.html) or [GO128](https://ia.cpuc.ca.gov/gos/GO128/go_128_startup_page.html), which is written by the [California PUC](https://www.cpuc.ca.gov), but are probably largely cribbed from NESC.